# Select where not exists pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a query

```
SELECT *
FROM  `user`
WHERE NOT
EXISTS (

SELECT *
FROM roleInEvent
WHERE user.userId = roleInEvent.userId
AND eventId = 1
)
AND user.disciplineId =5
```

Whenever I run this in my mysql console it returns 1 row. This is correct.
However in my php script it returns zero rows while it is exact the same query.

My php script looks like this:

```
    $db = DatabaseHelper::get();
    $st = $db->prepare('SELECT *
                        FROM  `user`
                        WHERE NOT
                        EXISTS (

                        SELECT *
                        FROM roleInEvent
                        WHERE user.userId = roleInEvent.userId
                        AND eventId = 1
                        )
                        AND user.disciplineId =5');
    $st->execute();

    if ($st->errorCode() !== \PDO::ERR_NONE) {
        return null;
    }
```

Somebody knows what is the problem here?

Comment: How do you know it returns zero rows? In the code you've posted, you're not even trying to get the results of the query.

Comment: Once a query is executed you must process the result set using some sort of Fetch [Here is the manual, Pick one](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)

Comment: Wow. You helped me a lot... I used return... It needs to be an echo for my javascript

Comment: Ok so it is answered, a self-answer posting by you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was easy.
I forgot to return the results to my javascript

Answer (score -1):

You can use too the `IN` with a `NOT` like:

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE id_user NOT IN ( SELECT other_data FROM roleInEvent WHERE user.userId = roleInEvent.userId AND eventId = 1 ) AND user.disciplineId =5
```

If the query: `SELECT other_data FROM roleInEvent WHERE user.userId = roleInEvent.userId AND eventId = 1` bring to you something, this result not have to exist in the `user` table.

Other example is:

Users Table:

```
---------------------------
id_user | name_user
1         fernando
2         urban
```

And in other table we have the block users:

Block Users:

---

```
id_user_block | id_user | name_user
1               1         fernando
2               2         john lennon
```

So,i want bring to me only users that not exists in the block users table:

The query will be:

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE id_user NOT IN ( SELECT id_user FROM blocked_users )
```

So, the last query we are getting:

```
id_user | name_user
2         john lennon
```

Greetings!